# React-Native App is not getting full page(till Notch) in Samsung fold device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fullscreen, samsung-galaxy

[screenshot for the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooai3.png)

apllication is working fine in all the device except samsung flip devices.

**react-native specifications used in the project:**

- System:

  - OS: macOS 13.2
  - CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8279U CPU @ 2.40GHz
  - Memory: 40.55 MB / 16.00 GB
  - Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash

  - Binaries:

    - Node: 19.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    - Yarn: Not Found
    - npm: 9.3.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    - Watchman: 2023.01.30.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  - Managers:

    - CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  - SDKs:

    - iOS SDK:

      - Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    - Android SDK: Not Found

  - IDEs:

    - Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386
    - Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

  - Languages:

    - Java: 11.0.18 - /usr/bin/javac
    - Python: Not Found
  - npmPackages:

    - @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    - react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    - react-native: 0.63.4 => 0.63.4
    - react-native-macos: Not Found
  - npmGlobalPackages:

    - *react-native*: Not Found

Any help will be appreciated.. TIA

I am expecting app must be open in full screen

Comment: mightBe possible that you wrapperd  component with <SafeAreaView> ... </SafeAreaView/>

Comment: @Kishan no we have not wrapped inside safeAreaView